# How to avoid showing session and firebase details on chrome network console

Tags: security, firebase-security, security-testing

we have application in node js which which can be opened in desktop chrome and uses firebase as backend . Right now all the request can be intercepted and shown on the chrome network console which be a security concern . How can we stop showing some request like url appended with file name or auth etc so that man in middle cant play

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the user can see their own requests in the developer tools of their own browser makes sense, and is not a security concern.

All requests to Firebase go over HTTPS connections, meaning that they are not susceptible to man-in-the-middle interception unless your entire network is already compromised.